# Parsing out Excel functions from Formula string

Tags: c#, regex, excel

I have a string which contains an Excel formula. How to parse out each particular function name from within the string?

I can't figure out how to write the regex for this. Basically it has to be the string of characters before a ( that isn't in a single or double quote.

For example:

1. `=VLOOKUP($A9,'Summary'!$A$10:$C$30,3,FALSE)` - Should return `VLOOKUP`
2. `=IFERROR((C10/B10),"N/A")` - should return `IFERROR`
3. `='New Chart Data (Date)'!L70` - Should return nothing because there is no function
4. `=IFERROR((C10/B10),Len(E30))` - should return `IFERROR` and `LEN`
5. `='New Chart Data(Date)'!L70 + Len(5)` - should return `Len`. This is the tricky one. A lot will return `Data` as well which is wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to do a regex with balanced text and know all the keywords and constructs/variable names before you can do this?

Comment: The string is already known to contain a formula, so these extra checks aren't needed.

Comment: So, no rules to parse formula .. interresting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this I guess...

```
(?<=[=,])[A-Za-z2]+(?=\()
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/vQ4fW5) (with descriptions of regex)

Actually, there's one catch: a formula such as `=IFERROR((C10/B10), Len(E30))` won't get `Len`. You can use this one instead and trim any spaces if any:

```
(?<=[=,])\s*[A-Za-z2]+(?=\()
```

Or since C# accepts variable length lookbehinds...

```
(?<=[=,]\s*)[A-Za-z2]+(?=\()
```

Which I think takes a bit more resources than the previous.

EDIT: I didn't think of the fact that sheetnames can take the form `=Sheet(2)` e.g. `='=Sheet(2)'!A1`

```
(?<=[=,])\s*[A-Za-z2]+(?=\()(?![^']*'!)
```

[revised regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/tO4xM3)

EDIT2: Forgot operators as well... I guess I'll use a word boundary like Andy's, since the only issue is

```
\b[A-Za-z2]+(?=\()(?![^']*'!)
```

[updated regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/sU3lY5)

Comment: Brilliant! (a few more)

Comment: Why do you need (?<=[=,]) at the beginning of the expression?

Comment: @Rafi It's to make sure there's either an equal sign or a comma before the text. It will avoid matches where you have a sheet name such as `Sheet(1)`. I forgot something else as well! Explained more in my answer.

Comment: @Jerry Good Point but it also won't match Len in #5. I just added #5

Comment: @Rafi Woops, and other operators! My my, I missed a lot. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: @Rafi I took a formula I made for another question and added it to the others, which I think makes the set to validate a bit more complete. [Updated regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/zM0pL5).

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be simplified, using a word-break `\b` rather than a look-behind:

```
\b([A-Za-z2]+)(?=\()
```

Comment: You've just added that ;). In which case, personally, I would still use my regex and create a Collection in C#, perhaps a `HashSet`, of all the Excel function names; there are around 300 of them. I would reject those matches that aren't in this list. (If someone uses a function name as a sheet name then I would give them a serious talking to!)

Comment: Alternatively, I might run two regex against the strings, one to strip out everything between apostrophes. But I guess you're still pursuing a single-regex solution :)